# Resource with Monsters Listed by Type?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, tool-recommendation

I just bought the Monster Manual and the Dungeon Masters Guide. I noticed that Monsters are organized by CR and locations but not by type. Is there any resource that lists Monsters by type so I can make encounters that contain all aberrations, all fey, all beasts, all undead etc.? I would like to avoid cataloging all the monsters by hand.

Comment: I voted not to close - this is not shopping for a game or system, this is not asking for bad subjective.  This is a clear and bounded question - what resources exist to sort monsters by type.

Comment: I am voting to close because this is asking for recommendations for a tool/resource and [tool recommendation question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-recommendation) are off-topic

Answer (score 4):

#### D&D Beyond catalogues all published monsters, and can be filtered by creature type.

[The monsters page](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters) at D&D Beyond does exactly this. The large circles at the top allow you to filter the database by creature type:

[image]

Additionally, you can filter the list further by all sorts of monster data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

D&D Beyond is probably the most fully-featured list for this purpose, as in Thomas’s answer; you don’t even have to buy the *Monster Manual* there if you just want to search for a monster, but I don’t think it will give you a page reference unless you own the source and view the full creature details. In addition, for those monsters which are in the free Basic Rules, the page reference given will be for the Basic Rules, which is less useful if you’re using the *Monster Manual*.

Thankfully there are many community-built tools that list monsters with sortable attributes, including type, which are designed to be used with a print copy of the *Monster Manual*.

One that I’d recommend and that I used before D&D Beyond is the Donjon Monster List; the site also has many other lists and tools, but the 5E Monsters list is here:

https://donjon.bin.sh/5e/monsters/

It includes all monsters from the *Monster Manual*, plus those from the later books *Volo’s Guide to Monsters*, *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes*, and the one that supersedes those, *Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse*. You can filter the list to show only monsters from a single source if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Google "D&D 5E MM spreadsheet"** and you should find plenty of options.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with *name, type, page, CR*. I don't know where I got it, but it may have been at [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/2gzgl4/5e_monster_manual_spreadsheet_all_creatures/). Those four columns are all it lists, so I hope it doesn't trample IP to link it.

Within the first five Google hits I found three resources that satisfy your request.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite spreadsheet: https://rpggeek.com/filepage/108409/bestiary

It lists every published monster to date, has around 20 columns of information about each one and has wonderful sorting features built in. It is updated within a week or two of each book being published.

Comment: Can you give more details about this resource than just a link to it? For example, unique traits or author qualifications.